# TYPO3 Upgrade 8.7 to 9.5 via composer folder structure and next step

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to Upgrade a TYPO3 8 instance to TYPO3 9 via composer. I hope you can help me.

I've tried the following:

```
composer remove dmitryd/typo3-realurl

composer remove typo3/cms

composer remove friendsoftypo3/extension-builder

composer remove typo3-ter/http2-push

composer require typo3/cms-about typo3/cms-adminpanel typo3/cms-backend typo3/cms-belog typo3/cms-beuser typo3/cms-core typo3/cms-extbase typo3/cms-extensionmanager typo3/cms-filelist typo3/cms-fluid typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content typo3/cms-form typo3/cms-frontend typo3/cms-impexp typo3/cms-info typo3/cms-install typo3/cms-lowlevel typo3/cms-opendocs typo3/cms-recordlist typo3/cms-recycler typo3/cms-redirects typo3/cms-reports typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor typo3/cms-scheduler typo3/cms-seo typo3/cms-setup typo3/cms-tstemplate typo3/cms-viewpage arminvieweg/dce:^1.6 georgringer/news:^7.0.6 helhum/typo3-console --update-with-dependencies --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Now i have a folder structure like:

```
-vendor
-var
-public
-|-typo3
-|-tpo3conf
-|-|-ext
-web
-|-fileadmin
-|-typo3conf
-|-typo3temp
-|-uploads
```

The LocalConfiguration, PackageStates, selfmade extensions etc. are in the /web/typo3conf folder. The Updated extensions are in the /public/typo3conf/ext folder.

This seems weird. What is the best practice to upgrade via composer or what would be the next step? Just move the fileadmin to public for example feels wrong.

Comment: Would you write your solution self her you likely found in TYPO3 Slack channel? https://typo3.slack.com/archives/C028J3N83/p1539941472000100

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem with the help of Helmut Hummel.

In addition you need to remove then unused 3rd party extensions such as realurl and update your custom extension if any.

```
composer remove typo3/cms-context-help typo3/cms-documentation typo3/cms-func typo3/cms-info-pagetsconfig typo3/cms-wizard-crpages typo3/cms-wizard-sortpages
```

and

```
composer require \
"typo3/minimal:^9.5" \
"typo3/cms-core:^9.5" \
"typo3/cms-about:*" \
"typo3/cms-belog:*" \
"typo3/cms-beuser:*" \
"typo3/cms-felogin:*" \
"typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content:*" \
"typo3/cms-form:*" \
"typo3/cms-impexp:*" \
"typo3/cms-info:*" \
"typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor:*" \
"typo3/cms-scheduler:*" \
"typo3/cms-setup:*" \
"typo3/cms-sys-note:*" \
"typo3/cms-t3editor:*" \
"typo3/cms-tstemplate:*" \
"typo3/cms-viewpage:*" \
--update-with-all-dependencies
```

The recommended place to store public accessible files is the "public" folder. Your fileadmin, typo3conf, typo3temp, etc. should be inside this folder now. I think in one of the older versions "web" has been used for that but should now be replaced by "public".